# When is the minimizer of the Lagrangian the solution to the primal problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This is a problem that came up when I studied the proof of the Newman-Pearson lemma/theorem, both in Van Trees' book "Detection Estimation, and Modulation theory" and Kay's "Fundamentals of statistical signal processing: detection theory".

The problem is (the functions are basically integrals of probability density functions, but that is not important here (I think))
\begin{aligned}
\min_x f(x)\\
\text{s.t. }  h(x) = 0
\end{aligned}
and I wish to find the solution to this problem, $x^*$. In the books, this is solved by forming the Lagrangian:
$$L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda h(x)$$
and minimizing this wrt $x$, giving the dual function
$$g(\lambda) = L(\hat{x}(\lambda), \lambda) = \min_x L(x,\lambda) .$$
We can then choose $\lambda^*$ in such a way that the constraint in the first problem is satisfied, i.e., $h(\hat{x}(\lambda^*) = 0.$ (We assume that there exists such a $\lambda^*$.)

**My question:** when does this procedure ensure that the obtained solution $x^*$ solves the original problem? In other words, what has to be assumed about $f(x)$, $h(x)$, $L(x,\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda)$ for this to hold?

**My thoughts:** It seems like this is some special case of basically solving the dual problem, instead of the primal problem, but stopping half way through. It seems reasonable to me that if there is a unique minimizer for the Lagrangian, this should be the one minimizing the original problem, but I base this on (probably) flawed intuition.

A related question, asking about (basically) the converse to my question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/877137/181493).

**Edit**
I feel I need to clarify something. To me, the way this problem is solved seems to be kind of a "shortcut" to solving the dual problem. Instead of finding $\lambda^*$ by maximizing the dual function, it is found by looking at the primary constraint. Is this always the case? Or does this only hold if we have strong duality? Or is there another sufficient condition?

Comment: It is not an accident that the other question you linked to uses $h(x)\leq 0$ instead of $h(x)=0$. Your problem is not convex unless $h$ is affine (which would make it rather uninteresting).

Comment: @MichaelGrant Ok. Because there is a slight difference in the proofs in the different books. Van Trees uses the formulation with an inequality constraint, while Kay uses the formulation in the question. They both reach the same conclusion though. I'm just curious why/how both of them seem to take this easy road over Lagrange multipliers, without explaining why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You basically, If I got you write, ask when Strong Duality holds.

Well, there are countless of edge cases but the simplest one is [Slater Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition).

Simply:

1. If the objective function is convex.
2. If the Equality Constraints are affine.
3. If the inequality constraints are convex.
4. If the domain all above are defined on is convex.

The above states a Convex Problem.
Slater Condition simply says:

5. The Domain isn't empty.
6. There is a point in the domain which holds all inequality constraints in strict form or all inequality constraints are affine.

If (5) and (6) hold then the problem is guaranteed to hold Strong Duality -> The dual solution is identical to the primal solution.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. It might very well be that the answer to my question is "when strong duality holds", but it isn't obvious to me. If strong duality is sufficient to solve it like this, is there an easy proof? I mean, if strong duality holds, I could maximize the dual function and find $\lambda^*$. But it seems like this "shortcut" doesn't bother with maximizing the dual,but instead looks at the original problem again, and says that $\lambda^*$ is chosen to satisfy the given constraint.